# Principal payments

Tags: loans

I have had several business loans and understand that this is not by any means typical.

I noticed that for a year my payments were not decreasing the principal on the loan. When I asked the bank why, I found out that at some point my payments were getting applied to principal only. Now I am paying interest off that was not paid for 6 months or so.

My banker states that he can change all the interest payments to principal payments. I am confused to why this would be. If I make all my principal payments first then would the bank lose a substantial amount of interest?

This has happened on 2 of the 3 loans I have looked at so far.

If they are willing to change all the payments to principal only, would this be beneficial to paying less interest ultimately? I assume there would be an interest account accruing somewhere that would need to be paid off at the end of the loan.

I understand that typically you have a loan balance that would include interest and principal. My balance owed did not change when I continued to make same payment? It gets applied to interest. The balance on the statement must not be a true balance. There must be interest owed above the balance showed but why would they do this to start with? They applied full payments to principle only first in order for interest to get to be more than several payments[image]

Comment: This is confusing - you are saying your payments were treated as principal only, but your principal was not decreasing. Did you mean to say your payments were treated as _interest_ only?

Comment: @void_ptr It sounds like there were 2 phases: first, principal only, then (currently) interest only. In the second phase, the principal owed stopped decreasing.

Comment: (I see you re-posted this question and now it's pointing here so you're obviously still trying to solve this.) Did the bank claim they made a mistake? Could you provide two consecutive statements for one of the loans in question? (Obviously blank out any personally identifying info.) Or at least provide the line items that the statements provide. You should see items on each statement for beginning balance, ending balance, payment, interest, all the dates, etc. Also let us know the interest rate and the amount of your payments. This will help provide more insight.

Comment: And btw, editing the question to make it more clear would allow it to be re-opened.

Comment: @TTT I edited the question to clarify the issue.  I attached a picture of the interest payments.

Comment: So that statement makes it look like an interest only loan, since the entire payment is going towards interest and the balance does not change. But the rate for a payment in that amount would be more like 12.2%, not 7.25%. Was your rate higher last year?

Comment: Also, did the bank claim they made a mistake?

Comment: @TTT The interest rate was lower the previous year.  Than bank did not admit if they did or did not make a mistake. He did say that he could apply all payments to principle if I wanted.  I am trying to get a better handle on this before I contact them again.  I belive if he can do this that the interest rate would have to be recalculated and reduced but do not understand why they would do this to start with.

Comment: If the interest rate was lower than 7.25% for 2018 then I agree that something is wrong- those statements are incorrect. I suppose you're going to have to go back to even earlier statements. It sounds like what you're saying is maybe at some point the earlier statements will show that the entire payment was applied to principal with $0 applied to interest. Can you go back even further and see if that's true?

Comment: @TTT yes that was the case that for some time we paid just principal.  I dont understand why they would do this.  I am going to contact them today to see if they can give me an explanation.

Comment: Wow- that's interesting. I think the reason this was closed as "unclear" is because what you're describing is kind of unbelievable. If you can find a statement showing only reductions in principal and update your question with it I'd definitely vote to re-open this as it would no longer be "unclear".

Answer (score 18):

**tl;dr:** To answer your specific question, there is no such thing as "principal only" or "principal first" loan. Every payment you make will be applied to accrued interest first, then anything more than that will (usually) be applied to principal. The main payment scenarios are "interest only", or "interest and principal". If you make *extra* payments beyond the minimum monthly payment, then that amount could be considered "principal only".

**Details:** Term loans have a set amount of interest and principal that you should pay each month. This is calculated as your minimum payment. Some loans offer an initial time period called "interest only" which means you only have to pay the accrued interest for the month without any additional principal during the time period. The advantage of this is the minimum payment is lower, but the downside is you don't make any headway into paying down the loan. It sounds like your loan was in the interest only period so if you didn't pay more than the minimum payment you wouldn't have lowered your starting balance.

If in any month you paid less than your minimum payment, then that means you didn't even cover the accrued interest so the total amount you owe will increase. Typically if you do this it is considered a late payment and can negatively affect your credit score. However, if you are granted a period of forbearance due to financial hardship, the bank will agree to let you reduce your monthly payment (possibly to $0) until you get back on your feet. It sounds like this is probably what happened in your situation. This is common with student loans after you are done with school and can't afford to make full payments yet.

As for next steps, if your loan is still in "interest only" mode, you can always pay more than the minimum payment each month to ensure you pay down some of the principal. If you can afford it then you could take the lender up on their offer to convert it to a term loan now so that your minimum payment will include principal right away. Even then you can (probably) still overpay any time you wish to lower your total amount due. When you speak to your lender it's a good idea to confirm that any payment amount more than the minimum payment will be applied to principal rather than future payments. Normally that's the default, but not always.

Comment: "you can always pay more than the minimum payment each month to ensure you pay down some of the principal." That depends on the details of the contract.

Comment: @glglgl of course. I clarified that a few sentences after that statement. 

Comment: @glglgl Fun fact. MY car loan states that I must be ahead by three payments if I wish to start making payments against the principal only. My mortgage does not have such silliness.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus not to drag this off topic, but how can you get ahead by 3 payments _and not have made them against the principal only_? If you are current on your payments, and you make an extra payment, the only balance that _can_ be made against is the principal, because the interest balance is zero.

Comment: @asgallant No clue but [themz da rulez](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eV1qr.png). FWIW, my previous car loan allowed me to pay against the principal without restriction.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus wow...that is terrible. They get to keep your money as a prepayment, not reduce your interest owed or principal, and not pay you interest on that money while they hold it as prepayment. While I wasn't particularly inclined to do business with Wells Fargo before, I'm now putting them on my list of "never do business with them ever" banks.

Comment: @asgallant My mortgage is held with Wells Fargo, lol. Not sure if it matters but my previous loan was on a new car at 0.9% but this loan is on a used car at ~3.5% so they may just be hungry for that interest money or maybe these terms give the dealership some sort of kick-back. Also, I do not recall the dealership giving me a choice of lenders. I know they say you should shop around for lenders before getting a car but I was lazy.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - I wonder if that's just the default, and you can opt to change that, or make a payment a different way. This seems to suggest you can make principal payments without being 3 ahead: https://eservices.wellsfargodealerservices.com/Help/GetHelp?help=HelpPrincipalBalance

Comment: @TTT Interesting, I am already subscribed to ALP and my screenshot is based on me clicking "Make a Payment" which probably assumes a one-time thing. I did not check if my ALP could be changed to include additional principal.

Comment: @TTT Wow, well I can change my ALP to include a principal...

Comment: @asgallant See the comments above.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus - that makes sense, I bet you're right- you'd have to change the monthly payment amount. But that's annoying that they make you jump through hoops like that. Sometimes you just want to make a one-time additional payment from a bonus or tax refund and it would be nice to just login and do it. Having to mail something or go to a branch... ug. Hehe.

Comment: It sounds to me like the bank simply made a mistake (probably a result of something getting pushed to production that _really_ shouldn't have. I've seen my fair share of fuck ups). For a period of time OP's entire payment was deducted from the principal, _when it shouldn't have._ So now the bank is making him pay back the interest he would have owed if the payment processing system hadn't screwed up; that means the principal is no longer going down. Once the current situation becomes aligned with the amortization plan again, the payments will start behaving normally once more.

Comment: @Demonblack - I don't think that's what happened because the concept of putting a payment towards "interest" or "principal" doesn't make a difference. From an accounting standpoint interest simply increases the loan amount each month, and payments decrease it. Maybe the bank forgot to charge interest for a while, but that doesn't seem likely...

Comment: @TTT That dependes heavily on how the system is implemented. The most straigthforward way to calculate the new principal is to calculate interest due for last month, subtract that from the amount paid, and deduct the remainder from the principal. An error where the entire payment got deducted from the principal instead of the remainder is not that far fetched, all it takes is subtracting the wrong variable (probably only in some obscure edge case involving legacy systems that wasn't tested properly).

Trust me, I've seen errors like that that had been in production for years.

Comment: @Demonblack - see Lawrence's answer, which explains why it doesn't make a difference if you apply it towards principal or interest. The end result is the same. (But I agree that banks sometimes make mistakes!)

Comment: @TTT As another example, one of my current banks has started offering car insurances, and they have a bug that puts me in the lowest bracket instead of the starter one, effectively cutting my premium in half. This bug has been in production for at least 7 months because I first noticed it in February when I did a quote just for the lulz. I'll probably take advantage of it next year and see what happens.

Comment: @TTT Lawrence's answer doesn't apply because it assumes that the calculations are done correctly. What I'm implying is that the interest is effectively never billed due to an error, so it's being counted as if you're paying <interest> dollars more every month than you actually are.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98088/discussion-between-ttt-and-demonblack).

Answer (score 1):

Money is fungible, so it doesn’t matter whether the dollar you pay is labelled *principal* or *interest*.

Case 1: interest is calculated on the amount owing.

Suppose you owe $5000 and accrue $50 interest in one period. Your total amount owing is now $5050. If you pay $150, you reduce the amount owing to $4900. You might call it $50 interest + $100 principal or $120 principal + $30 interest etc, but the next round of interest will be calculated based on the same figure: $4900.

Case 2: interest is calculated at the start of the loan and the dollar amount of interest is fixed.

Suppose you borrow $5000 and the terms call for a fixed $1000 interest over the life of the loan. That means you need to repay $6000 all up. I have seen these described as something along the lines of “interest first”. But if you pay $150 one period, you’re reducing the amount remaining to be paid from $6000 to $5850 regardless of whether you label that $150 *principal* or *interest* or some combination thereof.

So the label doesn’t affect how quickly the loan is discharged - you’re just working on repaying the loan in either case.

The label matters when it comes to tax. If you can deduct interest payments or if the lender must pay tax on interest received, but capital paid or returned isn’t taxable, the label affects the timing of the tax effect.

For example, if you called your initial payments “interest”, you might be able to claim a deduction early on, but the lender will need to pay more tax early on. If you called it principal, the tax effects might be deferred to a later year.

You also ask in comments about why the balance remains the same even though you continue to make payments. Here’s one possibility: you only paid the interest generated since the last statement. For example, if the balance was $120,000 and the monthly interest was $500, the accrued balance at the next statement should be $120,500. But if you pay $500, it drops the balance back to $120,000. It would look like the balance is unchanged - it was $120,000 on the previous statement and after payment is still $120,000. That’s just because the payment exactly matched the interest for that month.

There may be other reasons for payments not appearing to reduce the balance, but working through the specific details should be done with an appropriate professional such as an accountant who can privately examine the financial records with you.

—

*Disclaimer: I am not qualified as either a financial advisor or lawyer, and this answer is not to be relied on as financial or legal advice. Please seek professional advice as appropriate.*

Comment: It does matter if the lender maintains separate numbers for "money owed" and "money already paid toward the next ordinary installment", where interest is calculated on he _former_, and the _latter_ draws no interest.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Agreed, but that’s consistent with my answer. Your “money owed” is the same sum regardless of the split between principal and interest (e.g. $5000 owed, of which $4850 is considered principal and $150 is considered interest, has the same interest charged the next period as $5000 owed, of which $4000 is considered principal and $1000 is considered interest). Your “money already paid ...” likewise doesn’t change the interest of the next instalment regardless of the split between amounts paid towards capital and towards interest.

Comment: Funny, I just responded to a comment on my answer, then scrolled a bit and realized your answer is essentially identical to that comment. I agree with your sentiment here.

Comment: Why dose my balance owed not change when I continue make same payment? It gets applied to intrest.  The balance on the statment must not be a true balance. There must be intrest owed above the balance showed but why would they do this to start with?  They applied full payments to principle only first in order for intrest to get to be more than several payments.

Comment: @Jay If you make a payment, it should be reflected somewhere. If it doesn’t show up anywhere and your banker isn’t helpful, have a chat with your accountant and/or lawyer.

Comment: @Lawerenc it shows on the statement as applied to intrest but it dose not show how much interest is still owed.

Comment: @Jay I’ve edited to add one possibility for that.